# how I could regex ruby replace by group 10 using gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

Im trying to gsub replace a string using a group 10 but instead of this ruby replace by group 1 and 0 
I use this  in gsub replacement

```
gsub   \\10xp
  "smnm nmnmn nmnmn dsdsf sffddf sffdfd dfsff fdsdsfd fsdds ssfsff".gsub(/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)/,"\\10xp")
```

for replace and obtain the group 1 and the string "0xp"

How I could solve this

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to reference a double digit capture group, but you can always just reference a name with something like:

```
"smnm nmnmn nmnmn dsdsf sffddf sffdfd dfsff fdsdsfd fsdds ssfsff".
  gsub(/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (?<ten>\S+)/,
       '\k<ten>xp')
# "ssfsffxp"
```

Comment: This is the only way in Ruby. [Other regex engines have means to handle these situations](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html).

Answer (score 2):

No one known regex engine does support unnamed groups beyond `[0..9]` region. Use [`named_captures`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures) instead, or use uncaptured groups `(?:...)`, or use wiser regex:

```
"smnm nmnmn nmnmn dsdsf sffddf sffdfd dfsff fdsdsfd fsdds ssfsff".
  gsub(/((?:\S+\s+){9})(\S+)/, "\\1 \\2xp")

#                      ⇑ second group
#                  ⇑⇑⇑ nine times
#        ⇑⇑⇑ don’t capture this!
#       ⇑ first group
```